# how to convert 4-e7 to decimal in bash?

Tags: bash

I have outputs like this and I want to create a bash script to convert it to decimal

for example:

```
4e-7 to decimal is 0.0000004
2e-6 to decimal is 0.000002
3e-9 to decimal is 0.000000003
1e+4 to decimal is 10,000
```

How do I convert those samples using bash?

I want to automate it like:

```
    ./convert.sh 2e-6
    converting decimal >> 0.000002
```

is it possible?

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: its an output yml config from a python program

Comment: Then fix the output in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the printf from shell

For 4e-7

```
$ printf '%.7f\n' "4e-7"
0.0000004
```

For 1e4

```
$ printf '%8f\n' '1e4'
10000.000000
```

Use following appropriately to print commas in number

```
LC_NUMERIC=en_US

$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US printf "%'.f\n" 123456789
123,456,789
```

Comment: Doesn't match expected output, though. There are trailing 0s and no comma every 3 digits.

Comment: Just change the formatting number. For e.g. 
$ printf '%.7f\n' '4e-7'
0.0000004

Comment: This wouldn't be very convenient for different numbers.

Comment: But maths wise extra zeros does not matter, just keep it higher number in your desired range.